# Addition of an integer with an hex string

Tags: c++

What should I do to add an integer to an hex string.

Say my hex string is:

```
11'h000
```

And I want to add integer 7 to it. Output it should give should be

```
11'h007
```

If given 11'h00e, Adding integer 1 to it should give me 11'h00f.

Are there any predefined functions in c++? I could have write my switch-case statements to get it but looking for a compact way.

Comment: take a look at [std::soti](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/) and [std::to_string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/)

Comment: @Garf365: Even in C++11 you can't *easily* use `std::to_string` to output a hexadecimal string. Seems like the best way is still via the `std::hex` stream formatter. But I hope I'm wrong.

Comment: @Bathsheba you're right, the best way still `std::hex`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way? Don't confuse formatting of a number with a number.

Use

```
int x = std::stoi(s/*a hexadecimal string*/, nullptr, 16 /*hexadecimal*/);
x++; /*all your arithmetic operations here*/
std::cout/*or a suitable stream*/ << std::hex << x;
```